# How To Call Middleware Without Define In Web.php or Controller In Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want Call this middleware in All Route Without Define in Web.php or controller and please give some deeply idea about Middleware. like `middleware` `middlewareGroups` `routeMiddleware` and also give some idea about permission in laravel.(Role Wise)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class KeyTokenExist
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

            return redirect('/admin/employee');

    }
}
```

THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to [the global middleware stack](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L9) in `app/http/kernel.php`.

However if you will add a redirect here, your website will redirect indefinitely.

Comment: can you please give me explaination of all type of middleware how to use in laravel with any example i want understand deeply knowledge about Middlewarw THANK YOU@jerodev

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you need to know about middleware: [Laravel Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware)

It is as deep as it can go. There is no point of copy-pasting the same data over here.

Comment: Thank you @Learner